# Methods from my class not working after importing a module

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've been trying to import a class I made in a different js file, but every time I do so, all of my methods go undefined. Here's how it's currently looking.

Class file:

```
  export default class Disco {
    constructor(nombre, interprete, anyo, genero, localizacion = 0, prestado = false, caratula = 'imagen.png') {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.interprete = interprete;
        this.anyo = anyo;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.localizacion = localizacion;
        this.prestado = prestado;
        this.caratula = caratula;
}

    changeLocalizacion(nuevaLocalizacion){
    this.localizacion = nuevaLocalizacion;
}

    changePrestado(){
    this.prestado= true;
}

    showInfo(Disco){
    let info = `Disco: ${this.nombre} Interprete: ${this.interprete} Año: ${this.color} Género ${this.genero} Localización: ${this.localizacion} Prestado ${this.prestado} Caratula: ${this.caratula}`;
    document.getElementById("infoDisco").innerHTML = info;
}
}

let d1 = new Disco("Black Holes and Revelations", "Muse", "2006", "Rock");
let d2 = new Disco("The Resistance", "Muse", "2009", "Rock");
let discoteca = [d1, d2];
```

Script file:

```
import Disco from './disco.js';
let d1 = new Disco("Black Holes and Revelations", "Muse", "2006", "Rock");
let d2 = new Disco("The Resistance", "Muse", "2009", "Rock");
let discoteca = [d1, d2];


function countDiscos(){
    let number = discoteca.length();
    document.getElementById("numberOfDisks").innerHTML = number;
    
}

function fillTabla(){
    const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tabla tbody");
    if (tableBody) {
      tableBody.innerHTML = discoteca.map(disco => `<tr><td>${disco.nombre}</td><td>${disco.interprete}</td><td>${disco.anyo}</td><td>${disco.genero}</td><td>${disco.localizacion}</td><td>${disco.prestado}</td><td>${disco.caratula}</td></tr>`).join('');
    } else {
      console.error('Table body not found.');
    }
}

function showTabla() {
  const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tabla tbody");
  tableBody.classList.toggle('tabla');
}

function disksInBetween() {
  let anyo1 = document.getElementById('anyo1').value;
  let anyo2 = document.getElementById('anyo2').value;
  let anyosInBetween = discoteca.filter(disco => disco.anyo > anyo1 && disco.anyo < anyo2);
  if (anyosInBetween) {
      const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tabla tbody");
      tableBody.innerHTML = anyosInBetween.map(disco => `<tr><td>${disco.nombre}</td><td>${disco.interprete}</td><td>${disco.anyo}</td></tr>`).join('');
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Ejercicio 4</title>
    <script src="disco.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<style>
  #tabla { 
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3">Lista de Discos</h1>
            Bienvenido! ¿Qué deseas hacer hoy?
            <br>
            <button onclick="countDiscos()">Contar discos</button>
            <button onclick="displayTablaDiscos()">Ver todos mis discos</button>
            <button onclick="disksInBetween()">Contar por intervalo</button>
            <button onclick="addDisco()">Añadir disco</button>
            <button onclick="deleteDisco()">Borrar disco</button>
            <button onclick="showInfo()">Consultar disco</button>

            
            <table class ="table table-dark table-striped-white" id="tabla">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                  <th scope="col">Interprete</th>
                  <th scope="col">Año</th>
                  <th scope="col">Género</th>
                  <th scope="col">Localización</th>
                  <th scope="col">Prestado</th>
                  <th scope="col">Caratula</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to import this class so I could have an array of objects built from it on another js file so I could work with them. Instead, I keep getting this warning every time I use one of these methods:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IVxI.png)